# What is the difference between min and max constraint problems?

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

For example, let's consider these two min max optimization questions

**(1)** $$\max \ \ g(x,y)=xy$$ $$ \text{s.t. } x^2+y^2=1$$

**(2)** $$\min \ \ g(x,y)=xy$$ $$ \text{s.t. } x^2+y^2=1$$

---

**Solution:**

By using Lagrange multiplier,

For max problem (1),

$$L= g(x,y) +\lambda (x^2+y^2-1)$$

For min problem (2),

$$L= g(x,y) -\lambda (x^2+y^2-1)$$

---

What is the difference between max and min problem solution?

Is the Lagrange function I wrote above correct for max and min problems?

Please inform me on this subject.  I am confused too much:(

---

By Daniel Robert Nicoud's answer,
I try to solve the question

[image]

[image]

[image]

I took second derivatives (Heissan Matrix) please explain  meanings of  "less than zero " and "bigger than zero"

Comment: At a guess, one of $x$ and $y$ changes sign

Comment: How? Please show me the correct Lagrange functions for both? Thank you @Henry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the Lagrange multiplier method is used to find critical points, so you can use the same sign for both. The distinction between minima, maxima and saddle points is given by the Hessian matrix.

Comment: Okay thank you. I added My solution into  the question box. please look at the picture. I took second derivatives (Heissan Matrix) please explain  meanings of  "less than zero " and "bigger than zero"  I try to prove that the points I found in necessary condition are maximizer and minimizer of the function g(X,y). At the end, I cannot conclude. :(

Comment: For minimum problem, I find "$\gt 0$" And for maximum problem, I find "$\lt 0$". what do these mean?

Comment: Well done, good work. If the Hessian matrix is positive definite (the $>0$ case), then you have a local minimum, if it is negative definite a local maximum. You have a bit more details on the wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hessian_matrix#Second_derivative_test

Comment: thank you for your helps:)